# Submit AJAX form with multiple events

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

I have a form, and when the submit button is clicked, it sends an AJAX request. This works on the button click by:

```
$(#form).submit(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
    // ...
  })
});
```

The form data is passed to the URL in the ajax command using `data`.

Is there a way this form can be submitted and the same AJAX function can run on a dropdown change javascript/jQuery event? The dropdown menu is in the same form.

I have it so that when the AJAX returns successfully, it adds the HTML to populate a `div` with a `table` so this needs to be written once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: "Yes". You can call the "submit" method of the form from anywhere you like. For example:

```
$("#someDropdown").change(function() { $("#form").submit(); });
```

Demo:

```js
$(function() {
  $("#someDropdown").change(function() {
    $("#form").submit();
  });

  $("#form").submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log($(this).serialize());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="someDropdown">
  <option>Option 1</option>
  <option>Option 2</option>
</select>
<hr>
<form id="form">
  <input type="text" name="text1" />
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Documentation: https://api.jquery.com/submit/

Comment: Oh wow! it was that simple. I thought I tried that but I think i was trying the run the event.preventDefault() inside the .submit() inside .change(). That makes a lot of sense. Thank you for your help

Comment: @Ryan No problem. If the answer helped you please remember to mark it "accepted" (click the tick mark next to the answer so it turns green) - thanks.